# Rails error: unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been getting this error:

> /home/shaili/project/app/models/inbox.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected
>   end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

I am trying to add a search bar and have been also trying to set a path of the same page.

This is my models/inbox.rb file:

```
class Inbox < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', '%#{search}%'])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

This is the part of my Inbox_controllers file:

```
@inbox = Inbox.search(params[:search])
```

This is the part of my inbox.html.erb file where I am trying to figure out the path of the same page:

```
<%= form_tag :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= search_field_tag :Search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you indent your code you will spot this sort of error much more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Missing an end at the end :) :

```
class Inbox < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', '%#{search}%'])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
end
```

Proper indentation will help you spot these errors even before you attempt to run.

Comment: thank you. Everytime I try to search it redirect me to the homepage. Any tips on how to set a path?

Comment: Thats a separate question. I'd have to look at your complete controller code and perhaps the routes file to answer that question.

Comment: Do you need my controller or routes.rb file?

Comment: You should submit a new question with details about that problem as it is quite a separate issue from this one.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the end for class

```
class Inbox < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', '%#{search}%'])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
end
```